# Excel DNA can handle variable # of parameters (C# paramArrayAttribute)

Tags: c#, excel-dna

Now,Excel DNA can handle variable # of parameters (C# "paramArrayAttribute")
Such as,

```
[ExcelFunction(Description = " ",IsVolatile=true)]
public static object VI(params string[] optional)
{
   return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Excel-DNA Registration extension supports params registration and other type conversions: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration